# Is there an example dataset to illustrate cstore_fdw's performance benefits?

Tags: postgresql, columnstore, citus

I went through the examples in the [Citus quick start guide](https://www.citusdata.com/citus-products/cstore-fdw/cstore-fdw-quick-start-guide) with the `customer_reviews` dataset. It works great, but the performance on the same dataset in a regular PostgreSQL table was pretty good too. I suspect it's because the dataset might fit in RAM either way: I have a 4 CPU Linux VM with 8 GB RAM.

Can someone point me at a better dataset/query example to highlight cstore_fdw's utility, where the traditional row-store hits a wall with performance?

Answer (score 2):

I would generate data on the fly with something like:

```
node -e 'keys="pink penguins putter past potholes".split(" "), for (i=0; i<1000000; i++) console.log(JSON.stringify(keys.reduce((d,k) =>{ d[k]=Math.random(); return d; },{})))'
```

If you know what your JSON blobs will look like you can write a schema for them and generate random blobs with something like [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-random-instance)

[This page](http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/basics.html#hello-world) does a good job of describing JSON Schema. I can't remember which random json generator I used last but as long as it works it probably doesn't matter which you pick.

I am evaluating cstore myself at the moment. I have a hosepipe of JSON blobs already so I don't need to generate any more but for similar cases this is what I have done before.